# CA Offline Standard publish Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, security, certificate-authority, pki

I have a hierarchy of one offline CA (standard) and 2 subCAs (enterprise).

The offline CA is not published in Active Directory and the 2 SubCa's are published in AD.

Can the offline CA be modified to publish to AD so that it automatically installs the trusted root certificate on the machines without affecting the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

"Publishing to AD" involves using Active Directory to publish Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs) and the CA certificates via LDAP.  That is, relying parties download (pull) CRLs and intermediate CA certs using the LDAP protocol, instead of (or in addition to) HTTP.

Additionally, as relying parties trust AD they can trust the root CA certificate to be distributed by it and mege it into their certificate store.

You can also use Group Policy to distribute (push) the root CA (not the intermediates nor the CRLs) certificate to all relying parties, so that they can install them in their certificate store.  As Group Policies can be targeted this gives finer control over publishing to AD (if fine control is required).

Comment: Hi, I had seen that with the command "certutil -dspublish -f root.crt RootCA" you could publish the root certificate, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, that will publish it in Active Directory.  Each AD member computer will merge that into its certificate store as a Trusted Root Cert.  This will be AD wide though, whereas using Group Policy allows you finer grained control as to where the root CA cert is distributed.

Comment: In the case of having subdomains, would the teams of these subdomains also be added?

Comment: Your comment contradicts the statement in your answer then? @garethTheRed

Comment: @DavidTrevor - good spot :-) I always use group policy myself, which may explain why I forgot AD root cert distribution in my 1st attempt. Thanks for picking it up